# How can a script put itself in the background?

Tags: python-3.x

*Note: while a solution working on both MS Windows and Linux would be great, I am particularly interested in having it working in Linux (so Linux-only solutions are OK).*

I know that one can defer to the OS the backgrounding of a script

```
$ python3 myscript.py &
```

I however have a case where

```
(...)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # some long-lasting (= infinity) threads are started here
    (...)
    # here are some blocking checks which make sure that the threads were fully started
    (...)
    # now that the threads are fully initialized, I would normally perform a .join(), which will leave the script waiting for the threads to finish (which they will not)
```

I would like, instead (or in addition) to the `.join()` which will block, move the script to the background so that it can exit to the shell where other commands are subsequently launched. These commands are dependent on the correct start of the script above (this is the reason for the "blocking checks").

What are the mechanisms to use to perform such a task?

Comment: You can launch normally (without &), wait for the script to tell you that is ready, then ctrl+z and bg to move it to background.

Comment: @CătălinMatei: right, but the startup is unattended (in a bash script)

Comment: Ah, but if it's unattended it doesn't matter if it's in foreground or background. So the script just reads the commands and executes them when it's ready.

Comment: Or you can re-factor a bit of your script to launch a demon with the threads and exit with 0 when the demon is ready.

Comment: @CătălinMatei: please read my question (and please point out what was not clear): I need the script to block during the tests and **then** go into background. As for the launching - how to do that is the core of my question.

Comment: It goes into background with os.fork(). You launch processes with subprocess.run().

Comment: @CătălinMatei "t goes into background with `os.fork()`" No, it doesn't. `os.fork()` _forks_ a child process, it does _not_ put the parent process into the background.